# Aggregation in array element - python

Tags: python

I have a OP : `{'2017-05-06': [3, 7, 8],'2017-05-07': [3, 9, 10],'2017-05-08': [4]}`

from the OP I just want another OP :

`{'2017-05-06': [15, 11, 10],'2017-05-07': [19, 13, 12],'2017-05-08': [4]}`

which means:
*Ncleand* is `2017-05-06`
*element total* is `18` so `'2017-05-06': [3 -18, 7-18, 8-18] = '2017-05-06': [15, 11, 10]`
likewise all elements data.
So final output is `{'2017-05-06': [15, 11, 10],'2017-05-07': [19, 13, 12],'2017-05-08': [4]}`

How to do this?

Note : I am using python 3.6.2 and pandas 0.22.0

code so far :

```
import pandas as pd
dfs = pd.read_excel('ff2.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
dfs1 = {i:x.groupby(pd.to_datetime(x['date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))['duration'].sum() for i, x in dfs.items()}
d = pd.concat(dfs1).groupby(level=1).apply(list).to_dict()
actuald = pd.concat(dfs1).div(80).astype(int)
sum1 = actuald.groupby(level=1).transform('sum')
m = actuald.groupby(level=1).transform('size') > 1
cleand = sum1.sub(actuald).where(m, actuald).groupby(level=1).apply(list).to_dict()
print (cleand)
```

From the cleand I want to do this?

Comment: Why doesn't `[4]` become `[0]`? The element total of `[4]` is 4, and `4 - 4` is 0.

Comment: if the array element size < 1 then leave as it is.

Comment: Also, please post your code. We expect help seekers to make an attempt to solve the problem, and show proof of that attempt.

Comment: @Aran-Fey check updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a compact (but somehow inefficient) way:

```
>>> op = {'2017-05-06': [3, 7, 8],'2017-05-07': [3, 9, 10],'2017-05-08': [4]}
>>> { x:[sum(y)-i for i in y] if len(y)>1 else y for x,y in op.items() }

#output:
{'2017-05-06': [15, 11, 10], '2017-05-07': [19, 13, 12], '2017-05-08': [4]}
```

Comment: can we make if 2017-05-08': [0] then 2017-05-08': [1]? I mean make 1 where 0 in the element?

Comment: Sure. That would be:
`{ x:[sum(y)-i for i in y] if len(y)>1 else [1] if y == [0] else y for x,y in op.items() }`

Comment: This code needlessly computes the `sum` again each iteration over each of the lists. Don't try to cram everything into a comprehension or one-liner at the expense of readability and in this case, performance.

Comment: But where there is [0,0,0] then its printing [0,0,0] instead of [1,1,1]

Answer (score 2):

```
def get_list_manipulation(list_):
    subtraction = list_
    if len(list_) != 1:
        total = sum(list_)
        subtraction = [total-val for val in list_]
    return subtraction

for key, values in data.items():
    data[key] = get_list_manipulation(values)
>>>{'2017-05-06': [15, 11, 10], '2017-05-07': [19, 13, 12], '2017-05-08': [4]}
```